# oracle data integrator(ODI) connection with mongodb database

Tags: database, mongodb, oracle, jdbc, integration

In our system, we want to migrate our destination database to mongodb,
As of now we are using oracle database, we are trying to Connect MongoDB from ODI but we are facing error as URL is wrong, below is formatted URL
jdbc:mongodb:127.0.0.1:27017

I tried to used Cdata JDBC driver, we are able to create connection between MongoDB and Cdata JDBC driver but when trying to connect same URL from ODI we are getting below error

java.sql.SQLException: Driver class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] does not accept URL [jdbc:datadirect:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017]
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.doGetConnection(LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.java:144)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.getConnection(LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.java:73)
at com.sunopsis.sql.SnpsConnection.testConnection(SnpsConnection.java:1243)
at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet.getLocalConnect(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:173)
at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet.access$400(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:51)
at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet$5.doInBackground(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:629)
at com.sunopsis.graphical.dialog.SnpsDialogTestConnet$5.doInBackground(SnpsDialogTestConnet.java:625)
at oracle.odi.ui.framework.AbsUIRunnableTask.run(AbsUIRunnableTask.java:258)
at oracle.ide.dialogs.ProgressBar.run(ProgressBar.java:947)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] does not accept URL [jdbc:datadirect:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017]
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.doGetConnection(LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.java:144)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.getConnection(LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.java:73)
at oracle.odi.core.datasource.dwgobject.support.OnConnectOnDisconnectDataSourceAdapter.getConnection(OnConnectOnDisconnectDataSourceAdapter.java:87)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter$ConnectionProcessor.run(LoginTimeoutDatasourceAdapter.java:228)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Driver class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] does not accept URL [jdbc:datadirect:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017]
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:408)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:385)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:352)
at oracle.odi.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:331)
... 6 more